# Error - R 4.2.2 for macOS (ARM64) can’t be installed on this computer

Tags: r, error-handling, updates

I'm trying to install the latest version of R onto my computer, a Mac Mini. I usually use `updateR(`) from the updateR package. However, it isn't working and I'm getting an error.

```
library(updateR)
A new version R of 4.2.2 is available for update!
run updateR() to get the latest R on your macOS!
updateR()
Enter password for xyz: tuvwxyz
Updated ~/.Rprofile
Password:Installing R-4.2.2...please wait
Password:installer: Error - R 4.2.2 for macOS (ARM64) can’t be installed on this computer.
```

This hasn't happened before. I tried to download it manually and my mac gives the same error when I double click to load the package that "**R 4.2.2 for macOS (ARM64) can’t be installed on this computer**".

Anyone know what the issue is here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you selected the right package according to the processor build (Apple silicon / Intel) of your mac when manually downloading the package.
To confirm the processor for your mac, check under 'About this Mac'.

I had the same issue. My mac has the Intel processor and I downloaded the package for Apple Silicon arm64, which is why the package would not install. I installed the Intel 64-bit package and it worked. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue. updateR automatically selects the arm package  annoyingly but downloading it manually, and using the correct version, made it update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download GNU Fortran for arm64 from https://mac.r-project.org/tools/ .... It worked for me.... Let's hope it will for you ....

Answer (score 0):

Your mac may be not use M1. I encountered the same issue too. Your can try other edition for R 4.3.1 instead ARM64. It works for me. Good Luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).